# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mvc\Application' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, zend-framework2

So i've been following this tutorial:

```
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html
```

i'm at the point where i'm supposed to run phpunit -- i run the command `phpunit module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumControllerTest.php`

and i'm hitting a problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Mvc\Application' not found in /home/...rest of the folders here.../AlbumControllerTest.php on line 71
```

line 71 in AlbumControllerTest.php is:

```
$bootstrap        = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
```

When i look under Zend/Mvc/ i see a file called Application, so i'm assuming this is not the issue.

config/application.config.php looks like this:

```
<?php
// config/application.config.php:
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',                  // <-- Add this line
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),
    ),
);

?>
```

as per tutorial - i believe. Does anyone know how to solve this?!

Comment: why the down vote? at least give a reason?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue when upgrading from Magento Commerce 2.2.7 to 2.3.
I've fixed it by manually editing composer.json autoload:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {


        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    }
},
```

The, running the command:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your ZF2 is not autoloaded.

To setup zf2 and service manager for your module tests you can use https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/test/Bootstrap.php

in your test you will use it like this:

```
use YourNamespace\Bootstrap;

//...
public function setUp()
{
    Bootstrap::init();
    //...
    $this->controller->setServiceLocator(Bootstrap::getServiceManager());
}
//...
```